# Resistors max AC voltage datasheet

Tags: resistors, datasheet, mains

I want to make this circuit:
[image]

Where ***Sens2*** is mains (233VAC in Switzerland)

I found this resistor that look perfect for the job: RND 155SP12 3W ([datasheet](https://www.distrelec.ch/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/RND%20155HP%20series_eng_tds.pdf)).

I don't understand what does max voltage means for a resistor. For example, in the datasheet it says **Max working voltage: 250V**

Is it AC(RMS) or DC? Can I use this for mains? Is it the voltage drop only that I need to check?

Comment: Two resistors in series. Will be 500V. Good enough.

Comment: Thanks @user263983, so it is the voltage drop that I need to take a look only?

Comment: If it is proper placement, not too close. Datasheet shows amplitude,  RMS is used for calculating power dissipation. And it normal practice in high voltage put resistors in series

Comment: What would mean "not too close?" :)  I have 4 rows of 2 resistors next to each other: https://www.screenpresso.com/=ZgyTd

Comment: Not too close means proper spacing between points where s high voltage appears. Your design looks good but there is no info about PCB base material,  coat , etc. Resistors are OK.

Comment: Placing a part to mains AC voltage (233V nominal) can offer to your device much higher short time voltage pulses than 233VAC or 330V peak. That, of course depends on where in the mains 233VAC distribution network your device is connected. In an unlucky case an arc is ignited over the few millimeter gap between the ends of a resistor or inside the resistor. But the story can continue after the death of your device in a court of law. We can only hope that your device is the only dead. I guess you should learn something of safe designs for mains AC usage.

Comment: Thanks @user287001! I'm really trying to do so :) Any recommendation on where to start? I am using 4ma and calculated clearance and creepage for 7A (x1000), consuming 0.4W and using 3w resistors (x10), and dropping 114V per resistors, but buying 250V ones (x2) .. I am trying to make as big margin as possible. What I have no clue how to calculate is heat, and I am sure I am missing things, but hard to find out for a self learner. Any tips are super appreciated!

Comment: Your circuit is a kind of permanently wired measuring equipment. Find what CAT categories mean for measuring equipment - I mean CAT I, CAT II, CAT III and CAT IV. You are in safe if your device can stand the same as a meter which is selected properly for the connection point - depends on nominal voltage and placement in the power distribution network. Start from this: https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/what-are-multimeter-cat-safety-ratings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't exceed maximum temperature, maximum power dissipation, or maximum voltage across the resistor. In pulse applications, you need to be aware of the joule rating of the resistor. Bulk ceramic resistance elements are used in pulse applications to minimize spot heating within the resistance element. If you have the full 117VAC (165Vpeak) across a 39k resistor, that's about 0.35W, so your 3W resistor should be fine as long as it gets proper cooling. When consdering the maximum working voltage, be conservative and use the peak voltage since this is an arcing failure you are trying to avoid.

Exceeding the max working voltage, even though you are still under the maximum power rating, can cause small arcs within the resistive element. This grows to larger arcs and failure of the resistor. In pulse applications, it's fun to turn off the lights and watch 2 to 3 mm balls of orange flame emanating from resistor body when driven past the maximum voltage (above the max overload voltage).

The other specification is the maximum dielectric withstanding voltage which is what the resistor insulation can handle (arcing to other parts).

Answer (score 1):

The "max working voltage" in the datasheet is any voltage (be it AC or DC). This means it will work properly if it sees no more than 250V. Note the dielectric voltage is much higher, so the working voltage parameter has a margin for safety.

And, since you are using two equal series resistors, any voltage will be equally divided, so if you give it 233V (again AC or DC no matter) then each resistor will only see 117V, which is far below the specification, so you are good.

Using two series resistors is also a good safety practice with high voltage circuits. If one goes bad (short circuit itself), the other is there to protect from excessive current, so in this case the other resistor would see the full 233V and also be good.